# How can I get a visual indication if I muted audio and the battery power is running out?

Tags: gnome, power-management, shutdown, battery, gnome-power-manager

Is it possible to show a flickering or something else to indicate the shut-down process is nearby instead to get my attention with beeps?

Ubuntu Gnome here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Try to reinstall **NotifyOSD**

```
    sudo apt-get --reinstall install libnotify-bin notify-osd
```

Then restart.

2.Installing **Battstat Applet**  gives you a warning on top of all windows like this:-
http://techrax.tk/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/critical_message.png

To install it, do:-

```
add-apt-repository ppa:iaz/battery-status
apt-get update
apt-get install battery-status
```

Followed by

```
/usr/lib/battery-status/battery-status --indicator
```

Then just right click on panel and click on "**Add To Panel**">"**Battery Applet**"

Comment: I installed it. Both weren't installed in the first place. Restart done. My battery is low, what should I expect now?

Comment: You should get a bubble notification when the battery is low.

Comment: I get it. Is there another possibility to make the whole screen e.g. flashing? TY

Comment: Updated the answer, check it now!